# Filtering certain coins based upon name with CoinMarketCap

Tags: rest, coinmarketcap

I'm currently attempting to use the [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) but finding it frustrating.

I'm wanting to use this URL to query their API:

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest
```

However, rather than finding all, or just simply filtering based upon the number, I want to find a certain few coins.

So for example, I want to only find Bitcoin, Ethereum and Cardano.

Looking at their docs, it suggests you can sort by name, but it appears this is only listing them alphabetically, which I don't want to do.

So can anyone suggest how to query their API successfully and find just Bitcoin, Ethereum and Cardano using that GET URL above?

Here's the URL to the specific URL for the API request: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the endpoint [Quotes Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest):

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest
```

It allows you to pass a list of identifiers in a string as a parameter, like this:

```
1,1027,328
```

or a list of slugs:

```
bitcoin,ethereum,monero
```

or a list of symbols

```
BTC,ETH,XMR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to **scrape** information about new listings at crypto exchanges, you can be interested in this API:

https://rapidapi.com/Diver44/api/new-cryptocurrencies-listings/

It includes an endpoint with New Listings, New Pairs from the biggest exchanges and a very useful endpoint with information about exchanges where you can buy specific coins and prices for this coin at that exchange. It's a bit paid, but it's worth it!